# Get data from table with CakePHP 2

Tags: php, html, sql, cakephp

**What I have :**

I have a table named **Sales** and 3 colums named *Seller*, *Buyer* and *Price*.

In the controller, I have a *function myview()* where I do this SQL Query :

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total, seller_name, buyer_name
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller_name, buyer_name
```

The function :

```
public function myview() {
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all', 
  array(
     'fields' => array('SUM(price) AS total','seller_name','buyer_name'),
     'group' => array('seller_name','buyer_name')
  )
));
    }
```

I display the results in *myview.ctp* :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Seller</th> 
        <th>Buyer</th> 
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>PDF</th>
    </tr>

<?php

    foreach ($mysales as $thesales)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>       
        <td><?php echo $thesales['Sales']['seller_name']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $thesales['Sales']['buyer_name']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $thesales[0]['total']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="location.href='myview_pdf';" value="PDF"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    }
        echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
?>
```

The PDF button brings you to another view named *myview_pdf* where it displays (for now) a blank PDF.

**What I want :**

When you click on the PDF button, it "recognizes" the 'seller_name' and the 'buyer_name' of the line where I clicked the button so I can do this SQL query :

```
SELECT price, seller_name, buyer_name
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller_name, buyer_name
```

And display the results into the *myview_pdf.ctp*

**Problem :**

I'm struggling : how do I know which line I clicked, how do I fetch the datas from the line, where do I write the SQL query, how do I pass the query results into myview_pdf.ctp...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this a link first instead of a button, and pass the seller and buyer names as query strings.

```
<td>
 <!-- <input type="button" onclick="location.href='myview_pdf';" value="PDF"/> --> <!-- Remove this -->
 <?php echo $this->Html->link("PDF", array(
    "controller" => "<controller name>",
    "action"     => "myview_pdf",
    "?" => array(
       "seller_name" => $thesales['Sales']['seller_name'];,
       "buyer_name" => $thesales['Sales']['buyer_name'];,
    )
 )); ?>
```

And then in your controller, you can access the seller and buyer name from query string:

```
public function myview_pdf() {
     $seller_name = $this->request->query("seller_name");
     $buyer_name  = $this->request->query("buyer_name");
     /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: You again my hero ! So if understand correctly, now I just have to do "<?php echo $seller_name; ?>" in the myview_pdf.ctp ? Because when I do this I have a "Undefined variable" error. Sorry for the dumb question and sorry for the late reply I had to fix a few problems with the pdf

Comment: I found where the problem was : in myview_pdf() I have to write $this->set('seller_name', $this->request->query("seller_name")); instead of $seller_name = blablabla.

But now how can I use the value of seller_name in order to do a query like "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE seller_name = //the value of seller_name we received//" ? @ObjectManipulator

Comment: Are you suggesting that you'd write that query in the view? I'm afraid that's not the right approach. Your query should either be in the model or the controller. It should never be in the view. You're probably using some Pdf Helper, I'm guessing. Try using a component instead.

Comment: No in the controller. This is what I'm trying to do in the controller :      $this->set('seller_name0', $this->request->query("seller_name"));
    $this->set('buyer_name0', $this->request->query("buyer_name")); 
    
       $this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all',
            array(
                'fields' => array('something1','something2',something3'),
                'conditions' => array('seller_name' => $seller_name0, 'buyer_name' => $buyer_name0)
            )
        ));

Comment: I want to display every sales a seller#1 has done with a buyer#1, I think the problem is with the conditions in my previous comment (sorry if it's unreadable) @ObjectManipulator